# Use a loop to plot n charts and variable the title Python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a set of data (Excel) that I load into python using a pandas dataframe. What I would like to do is create a loop that will print every second column a plot for all the elements in a certain limit. My data is in an excel file structured in this fashion:

Index | DATE  | **W300** | W301 | **W303** | Wnnn |

I want only the strong marked columns to be printed, in summary evere second column (n+2).

This is what I have for code so far:

```
import pandas as pd  
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

data = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\marco\Desktop\HZ.xlsx', skiprows=0, sheet_name='Heizzonen')
gapminder = pd.DataFrame(data, columns= 
['W300','W301','W302','W303','W304','W305','W306','W307','W308','W309','W310',.............,'W800']

gapminder2=gapminder['W304'].iloc[25663:30703] 

hplot = sns.histplot(gapminder2, kde=False, color='blue', bins=100)
plt.title('W300', fontsize=18)
plt.xlabel('Temperatur [°C]', fontsize=16)
plt.ylabel('Häufigkeit', fontsize=16)
```

I want to plot n Chart and for each diagram, I want to use the variable to label them in the title. So that the loop goes for the column and the title.
I would provide my thoughts but i have no clue.

Answer (score 0):

Expression `gapminder.columns.to_list()` will give you the list of the column names. Using `[0::2]` (for even elements) or `[1::2]` (for odd elements) it's possible to get every second element of that list:

```
for col in gapminder.columns.to_list()[1::2]:
  column = gapminder[col]
  # here comes your logic
```